# Loading Spring Context Dynamically at Run-time in a Web Application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications, applicationcontext

I'm converting a standard Java Application that uses Spring Framework into a Web App. This application loads new Spring Context based on run-time parameters, that was done using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`.

So my question is how to do the same in a Web Application given that I already configured my web.xml and added Spring Listeners as below:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Another Problem, my deployment environment is on Tomcat 5.5 where I'm not able to see any logging during spring context loading to know what's wrong.

Comment: Do you mean at runtime or when your application starts up?

Comment: At Runtime after my application has already started.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually mean to load a configurable context on start up of your weblication you could configure your web.xml with a property placeholder for the context name.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:${my_context_file}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I like this parameter approach.

Answer (score 1):

To turn on logging you may need to set it in your log4j.properties file, like so:
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG

You also have to ensure that you are logging to the CONSOLE and not some other stream.  If you are then log messages should appear in catalina.out